# R plotly with add_annotations can't work

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I use Rstudio to draw a picture with plotly packages. But there are some bugs I can't understand.

**1)** Warning: Warning in origRenderFunc() :
Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "bcc122e50b9"; Shiny doesn't use them

**2)** The plotly object's function(like Pan,Zoom in,Zoom out, Autoscale,etc.) can run normally in web. But when I run R code on Rstudio. Once I click the Pan to move the picture, Rstudio stops working. Is it a problem in my code or Rstudio software?
You can use the following code for detail.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
positiox_positiony <- data.frame(x_position=1:2,y_position=3:4)
node_edge_xy <- data.frame(x=1,y=3,xend=2,yend=4)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(  
  plotlyOutput(outputId = "main_plot")  
))
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(positiox_positiony,aes(x=x_position,y=y_position))+
      geom_point(color="red",size=10,alpha=0.8)+
      geom_segment(data=node_edge_xy,aes(x = x,y = y,xend = xend,yend = yend))

    ggplotly(p)%>%
      add_annotations(showarrow = T,
                      text ='',
                      arrowhead=2,
                      arrowwidth = 2,
                      arrowside = 'srart+end',
                      opacity=1,
                      x=node_edge_xy$x,y=node_edge_xy$y,
                      ax=node_edge_xy$xend,ay=node_edge_xy$yend,
                      xref = "x",yref = "y",
                      axref = "x",ayref = "y")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Interestingly, when I turn the option 'showarrow = T' to 'showarrow = F',then the Pan function of plotly can normally use.

Comment: I tried running your code with `showarrow = T` as well as `showarrow = F`, it is working fine. The problem might be there with your system configuration.

Comment: You can use Pan function to drag the picture?   I don't know what's the matter with my system configuration.

Comment: Try installing the development version of plotly: `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right.@Marco Sandri